# Execute a sql string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My code is as below, somehow there is always an error near `@Name`

```
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(MAX)  =  '(mm.dll, ben and jerry.exe)'
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)= 'SELECT OrderName,
   customer.version,
   count(DISTINCT company.CID) as Counts
FROM [CompanyData] company
  INNER JOIN [vendor] mav on company.CID = mav.CID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Customer] customer on company.VendorId = customer.VendorId AND company.DId = customer.DId
WHERE OrderName in' + @Name+ '
  GROUP BY  
         customer.version, OrderName'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a single quote in your declaration of `@Name` and just remove the hashes(#) in it:

```
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(MAX)='(''mm.dll'', ''ben and jerry.exe'')'
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)= 
       'SELECT 
              OrderName,
              customer.version,
              count(DISTINCT company.CID) as Counts
        FROM [CompanyData] company
        INNER JOIN [vendor] mav on company.CID = mav.CID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Customer] customer on company.VendorId = customer.VendorId    
             AND company.DId = customer.DId
        WHERE OrderName in ' + @Name+ '
        GROUP BY customer.version, OrderName'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Hi @Rigel1121 thx for the prompt reply. But I don't think it is due to the `'` since the data is actually faked and even without `'` just like `'(apple and pear, orange)'` won't work as well

Comment: I think the problem might be the way I concatenate the sql string?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Since your values in your `WHERE` clause are strings, Don't forget to enclosed them in single quotes. See and try my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! The error changes this time since my actual data has a `.` in each value, such as `'mm.dll'` so the error seems to be the `.` do I have to escape `.` in sql as well? How could I do that in this case?

Comment: I have changed my values. Sorry for so much confusion

Comment: your answer is OK, but you need to explain well.@Rigel1121
tell him about `in[space]+ @Name+ '[space]` to your answer.

Comment: it works!!! Thanks!! I am very new to sql. I am just wondering why we don't need to put a '+' to concatenate string in `@Name`?

Answer (score 0):

Please add double quotes in @Name variable like..

```
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(MAX)  =  '("mm.dll", "ben and jerry.exe")'
```

Answer (score 0):

it would probably save you a lot of grief if you store your names into a table value;

```
DECLARE @a varchar(max) = 'Jerry.ede';    
DECLARE @b varchar(max) = 'Sa''ra';    
DECLARE @c varchar(max) =  '(''mm.dll''),(''ben and jerry.exe'')';

DECLARE @Names TABLE (name nvarchar(MAX));

INSERT INTO names values (@a),(@b);
EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO names values ' + @c;

SELECT OrderName,
   customer.version,
   count(DISTINCT company.CID) as Counts
FROM [CompanyData] company
  INNER JOIN [vendor] mav on company.CID = mav.CID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Customer] customer on company.VendorId = customer.VendorId AND company.DId = customer.DId
WHERE OrderName in (SELECT name from @names)
  GROUP BY  
         customer.version, OrderName;
```

Answer (score 0):

EXEC(@sql)
or
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Please add double single qoute in the string @name .

```
 DECLARE @Name nvarchar(MAX)  =  '(sally''s order, ben and jerry)'
 DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)= 'SELECT OrderName,
 customer.version,
  count(DISTINCT company.CID) as Counts
 FROM [CompanyData] company
 INNER JOIN [vendor] mav on company.CID = mav.CID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [Customer] customer on company.VendorId = customer.VendorId       
 AND company.DId = customer.DId
 WHERE OrderName in' + @Name+ '
 GROUP BY  
 customer.version, OrderName'

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: thx! but I think my actual problem is not because of that.. see the corresponding changes above