# How to use a column as an input in a tsql string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a followup question from [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179585/execute-a-sql-string-in-sql-server/29179598#29179598). My question is if I want to change the `@Name` to a specific column using `SELECT` how can I concatenate them together to the SQL string?

An example is as below: the `Name` column in `Customer` table looks like this:

```
| Name              |          
+-------------------+
| Ben and Jerry.exe |       
| 123od.exe         |             
| m2m.dll           |              
| lyy.exe           |
```

T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @NameTable = SELECT Name from Customer
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(MAX)  =  = '''' + REPLACE(@NameTable, ',', ''',''') + ''''
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)= 'SELECT OrderName,
   customer.version,
   count(DISTINCT company.CID) as Counts
FROM [CompanyData] company
  INNER JOIN [vendor] mav on company.CID = mav.CID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Customer] customer on company.VendorId = customer.VendorId AND company.DId = customer.DId
WHERE OrderName in' + @Name+ '
  GROUP BY  
         customer.version, OrderName'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: why don't you explain in your first question what you really want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't select records like `DECLARE @NameTable = SELECT Name from Customer`
from another table, you can create a temporary table for it.

like:

```
create table #tmpName(Name varchar(max))

insert into #tmpName(Name) SELECT Name from Customer
```

Your Answer:

```
create table #tmpName(Name varchar(max))

    insert into #tmpName(Name) SELECT Name from Customer

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)= 'SELECT OrderName,
   customer.version,
   count(DISTINCT company.CID) as Counts
FROM [CompanyData] company
  INNER JOIN [vendor] mav on company.CID = mav.CID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [Customer] customer on company.VendorId = customer.VendorId AND company.DId = customer.DId
WHERE OrderName in (' +(select Name from #tmpName)+ ') 
  GROUP BY  
         customer.version, OrderName'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

drop table #tmpName
```

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate all the values in a column, I think you need to do something like this.

```
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @name = ''

SELECT @name = 
    COALESCE (CASE WHEN @name = ''
                   THEN Name
                   ELSE @name + ',' + Name
    END,'')
FROM 
    Table
```

This going to give you all the strings in a column as a CSV.

if `Table` is a dynamic name you can use dynamic SQL as you are using in your query.

Sorry if this code has a mistype or mistake, I don't have a database server to try it.

Hope this helps